# Exported data become unknown character

Tags: mysql

May I know how to export MySQL data and prevent the data display a weird character?

This table uses to store the record about crawling information. It stores *IP, PatternSignature, status, updated and PTR*.

[image]

But whenever I export out the table, all the IP will become an unknown character which unable to import into database.

[image]

May I know how to rectify this issue?

Comment: A quick google suggests the datatype for `patternsig` is `binary`, so it makes sense that is not human readable in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put that kind of data in `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`; use only `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss in more detail.

Use `--hex-blob` on `mysqldump`.

If you are "exporting" by some other means, explain.